# Permutations on lists within lists sequentially

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have two lists and I would like to calculate the permutations between the two. I have been able to successfully do this using itertools, but am having trouble taking it further.

I have two nested lists:

```
list_1 = [0, 226, 68, 100, 70, 71, 42, 43, 44, 14, 16, 114, 210, 22, 87, 28, 125][10, 216, 67, 120, 70, 717, 42, 43, 445, 14, 87, 289, 125]
```

```
list_2 = [10, 9, 2, 1, 0][10, 216, 7, 10, 70, 717, 42, 3, 445, 14, 162, 87, 289, 125]
```

The first entry of `list_1` (`[0, 226, 68, 100, 70, 71, 42, 43, 44, 14, 16, 114, 210, 22, 87, 28, 125]`) needs to be permutated with the first entry of `list_2` (`[10, 9, 2, 1, 0]`). Then I need to get the permutations of the second entry of `list_1` with the second entry of `list_2`, etc.

The issue is that there will be no set number of entries in each list, so it is not feasible to simply make variables for `list_1[0]`, `list_2[0]`, etc.

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by permutate in this case?

Comment: What does it mean to permute one list with another?

Comment: A permutation is just a reordering of a set of numbers, e.g. the numbers 1, 2, and 3 have six permutations 123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321.

Comment: Why are your lists declared like that? IT looks like a syntax error from here.

Comment: These lists is the output from earlier code. The output I'm looking for is every iteration of `list_1` first entry with `list_2` first entry, for an output of:

```[(10,0),(10,226),(10,68)...(9,0),(9,226),(9,68)...(2,0),(2,226),(2,68)...]```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

list_1 = ([0, 226, 68, 100, 70, 71, 42, 43, 44, 14, 16, 114, 210, 22, 87, 28, 125],
          [10, 216, 67, 120, 70, 717, 42, 43, 445, 14, 87, 289, 125])
list_2 = ([10, 9, 2, 1, 0],
          [10, 216, 7, 10, 70, 717, 42, 3, 445, 14, 162, 87, 289, 125])

count = 0

for list1_item, list2_item in zip(list_1, list_2):
    print(f"{list1_item=} {list2_item=}")
    for permutation in itertools.permutations(itertools.chain(list1_item, list2_item)):
        if count % 10**8 == 0:  # print once in a while
            print(permutation)
        count += 1

print(count)
print(f"last permutation: {permutation}")
```

gives

```py
list1_item=[0, 226, 68, 100, 70, 71, 42, 43, 44, 14, 16, 114, 210, 22, 87, 28, 125] list2_item=[10, 9, 2, 1, 0]
(0, 226, 68, 100, 70, 71, 42, 43, 44, 14, 16, 114, 210, 22, 87, 28, 125, 10, 9, 2, 1, 0)
(0, 226, 68, 100, 70, 71, 42, 43, 44, 14, 210, 125, 10, 9, 114, 22, 0, 87, 2, 1, 16, 28)
(0, 226, 68, 100, 70, 71, 42, 43, 44, 14, 28, 16, 210, 22, 125, 9, 1, 2, 87, 10, 114, 0)
...
list1_item=[10, 216, 67, 120, 70, 717, 42, 43, 445, 14, 87, 289, 125] list2_item=[10, 216, 7, 10, 70, 717, 42, 3, 445, 14, 162, 87, 289, 125]
(10, 216, 67, 120, 70, 717, 42, 43, 445, 14, 87, 289, 125, 10, 216, 7, 10, 70, 717, 42, 3, 445, 14, 162, 87, 289, 125)
...
```